# How to stop JSoup/OkHttpClient: A connection was leaked?

Tags: android, jsoup, okhttp

My Android app uses Jsoup to connect to websites

```
implementation group: 'org.jsoup', name: 'jsoup', version: '1.11.2'
```

My logcat has these messages

```
OkHttpClient: A connection to http://www.xxx.yyy.zzz/ was leaked. Did you forget to close a response body?
```

My jsoup connection resembles: -

```
final Document feedNavigator = Jsoup.connect(uri.toString()).referrer(JSOUP_REFERRER).userAgent(USER_AGENT).followRedirects(true).ignoreContentType(true).ignoreHttpErrors(true).maxBodySize(JSOUP_MAX_BODY_SIZE).timeout(JSOUP_TIMEOUT).get();
```

I was under the impression jsoup handled its own resources.

Why am I getting these logcat warnings?

How can I resolve this leak?

Comment: Its not because of jsoup, its because of okHttp.

Comment: The only 3rd party library my app uses is Jsoup. It must be Jsoup thats employing okhttp.

Comment: this should be fixed in latest version. cross check if you are using the latest library

Comment: maven repository shows the version of jsoup I am using as the most recent version https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jsoup/jsoup/1.11.2

Comment: probably a bug in jsoup then.

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin I used this way :

```
try {
                val req: Request = Request.Builder().url(url).get().build()
                val client = OkHttpClient()
                val resp: Response = client.newCall(req).execute()
                val code: Int = resp.code() // can be any value
                body= resp.body()
                if (code == 200) {
                    body?.close() // I close it explicitly
                }
```